# Minimum support OS version for SafetyNet API

Tags: android, safetynet

I am using the Google SafetyNet API to detect device tampering in my application. Reference:: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/safetynet/package-summary

But I cannot find any reference to the minimum support OS version. I thought I read somewhere that it was 7.0 but can't find that now.

It used to say "since" in the API docs, which was useful to tell the requirements but that seems to have disappeared.

What is the earliest version of Android that SafetyNet will work on, as supported by Android? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> All Play-enabled Android devices using Android 2.3 and above already use SafetyNet as long as the Play Services package is updated.

[here](https://www.synopsys.com/blogs/software-security/using-safetynet-api/)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the prior response, Android 2.3. is the minimum supported version. However it should be noted that prior to Andoird 6.0, the SafetyNet could not read the device's bootstate, limiting the effectiveness of SafetyNet.

See [Slide 50](http://mulliner.org/collin/publications/inside_safetynet_attestation_attacks_and_defense_mulliner2017_ekoparty.pdf)